# Jasminejs - Test Callback

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Nested function (change) to be tested

```
this.options.edit = (e: any) => {
    let type: any = this.getTrasactionTypeText(e.container);

    if (type !== undefined) {
        let transaction: any = this.getTrasactionType(e.container);

        transaction.change(() => {
            console.log('testing callback');                
        });
    }
};
```

Jasmine Test

```
it('should call back the nested function', async(() => {

    class callback {
        change = function() { };

    }

    let call = new callback();

    spyOn(component, 'getTrasactionTypeText').and.returnValue('CLOSEREASON');
    spyOn(component, 'getTrasactionType').and.returnValue(call);        

    let object: any = jasmine.createSpyObj('object', ['container', 'model']);
    object.model = { isMurex: true, isBloomberg: true, isFidessa: true, isMartini: true };

    component.options.edit(object);

    call.change();//This is not calling the nested function
}));
```

Comment: You are spelling transaction with and without the middle 'n'. It's a good idea to fix this now before it catches someone out.

Comment: Thanks @MarkChorley

Answer (score 1):

```
call.change();//This is not calling the nested function
```

There's no reason it should. You are just calling a function there. I think that *you* think that you are firing an event, which is being handled by your code under test. That's not the right way to think about it.

Your code under test is just executing a function, and passing in an arrow function as an argument. One way to test would just be to check that your function is called. For instance, something like this (untested):

```
it('should call back the nested function', async(() => {    
  var callback = jasmine.createSpyObj('callback', ['change']);

  spyOn(component, 'getTrasactionTypeText').and.returnValue('CLOSEREASON');
  spyOn(component, 'getTrasactionType').and.returnValue(callback);        

  let object: any = jasmine.createSpyObj('object', ['container', 'model']);
  object.model = { isMurex: true, isBloomberg: true, isFidessa: true, isMartini: true };

  component.options.edit(object);

  expect(callback.change.calls.count()).toBe(1);
}));
```

Extending this further, you can check that the argument passed into the call is a function, which you can then execute yourself *in your test*, and assert against. For instance:

```
it('should pass a function into transaction.change()', async(() => {    
  var callback = jasmine.createSpyObj('callback', ['change']);

  spyOn(component, 'getTrasactionTypeText').and.returnValue('CLOSEREASON');
  spyOn(component, 'getTrasactionType').and.returnValue(callback);        

  let object: any = jasmine.createSpyObj('object', ['container', 'model']);
  object.model = { isMurex: true, isBloomberg: true, isFidessa: true, isMartini: true };

  component.options.edit(object);

  // Validate that the transaction.change() function was called once.
  expect(callback.change.calls.count()).toBe(1);

  // Validate that the function was given a single argument.
  var args = callback.change.calls.first().args;
  expect(args.length).toBe(1);

  // Validate that the single argument is itself another function.
  var actualFunc = args[0];
  expect(typeof actualFunc).toBe('function');

  // Execute the other function, and validate that it does xyz.
  actualFunc();
  // expect(...).toBe(...);
}));
```

Comment: Thanks @sethflowers. I see your point but still cannot test what is inside the change callback eg. console.log('testing callback');

Comment: @Acosta Yes you can. If you can access the "callback" spy, then you can access the arguments that are given to it. The only argument given to it is the function you are interested in. This means you can get it, and execute it, and run your assertions. Check the update to my answer for an example.

Comment: you are a star, returning the real func as arg made the trick, thanks